# What about partial recv() on two byte header containing message length?

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I have been reading some socket guides such as Beej's guide to network programming. It is quite clear now that there is no guarantee on how many bytes are received in a single recv() call. Therefore a mechanism of e.g. first two bytes stating the message length should be sent and then the message. So the receiver receives the first two bytes and then receives in a loop until the whole message has been received. All good and dandy!?

I was asked by a colleague about messages going out of sync. E.g. what if, somehow, I receive two bytes in once recv() call that are actually in the middle of the message itself and it would appear as a integer of some value? Does that mean that the rest of the data sent will be out of sync? And what about receiving the header partially, i.e. one byte at a time?

Maybe this is overthinking, but I can't find this mentioned anywhere and I just want to be sure that I would handle this if it could be a possible threat to the integrity of the communication.

Thanks.

Comment: Why should the messages go out of sync? If you use a TCP connection the TCP/IP stack of your OS is responsible for rearranging the packets correctly and deliver the bytes in correct order. If you use UDP then you get whole datagrams with correct order of the bytes inside. Only complete datagrams might be out of order.

Comment: Ok. Imagine message being composed of 2 bytes header and 10 bytes payload.
I connect and start receiving something. For some reason the sender starts sending a payload instead of header and since there is no guarantee that I receive the whole 10 bytes at once it might look like this: 4bytes, 3bytes, 2bytes and the last 1byte, hypothetically speaking. There in the middle of the payload I receive 2bytes and therefore assume that is a header. If I'm really unlucky, these bytes could represent a number such as 21. Then I assume I'm expecting a payload of 21 bytes, so on and so forth...

Comment: That won't work. The sender knows when the connection is established. He mustn't start in the middle of a message but must always transmit complete valid messages. Otherwise any receiver cannot handle the data reliably.

Answer (score 2):

It is not overthinking.  TCP presents a stream so you should treat it this way.  A lot of problems concerning TCP are due to network issues and will probably not happen during development.

Start a message with a (4 byte) magic that you can look for followed by a (4 byte) length in an expected order (normally big endian).  When receiving, read each byte of the header at the time, so you can handle it anyway the bytes were received. Based on that you can accept messages in a lasting TCP connection.

Mind you that when starting a new connection per message, you know the starting point.  However, it doesn't hurt sending a magic either, if only to filter out some invalid messages.

A checksum is not necessary because TCP shows a reliable stream of bytes which was already checked by the receiving part of TCP, and syncing will only be needed if there was a coding issue with sending/receiving.

On the other hand, UDP sends packets, so you know what to expect, but then the delivery and order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Your colleague is mistaken. TCP data cannot arrive out of order. However you should investigate the MSG_WAITALL flag to `recv()` to overcome the possibility of the two length bytes arriving separately, and to eliminate the need for a loop when receiving the message body.

Answer (score 0):

Its your responsibility to make you client and server syncing together, how ever in TCP there is no out of order delivery, if you got something by calling recv() you can think there isn't anything behind that that you doesn't received.

So the question is how to synchronize sender and receiver ? its easy, as stefaanv said, sender and receiver are knowing their starting point. so you can define a protocol for your network communication. for example a protocol could be defined this way :

> 4 bytes of header including message type and payload length
>
> Rest of message is payload length

By this, you have to send 4 byte header before sending actual payload, then sending actual payload followed.

Because TCP has garauntied Inorder reliable delivery, you can make two recv() call for each pack. one recv() call with length of 4 bytes for getting next payload size, and another call to recv() with size specified in header. Its necessary to make both recv() blocking to getting synchronized all the time.

An example would be like this:

```
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE       1024 // something you know

char  buf[MAX_BUF_SIZE];

int recvLen = recv(fd, buff, 4, MSG_PEEK);
if(recvLen==4){
    recvLen = recv(fd, buff, 4);
    if(recvLen != 4){
          // fatal error
    }
    int payloadLen = extractPayloadLenFromHeader(buf);

    recvLen = recv(fd, buff, payloadLen, MSG_PEEK);

    if(recvLen == payloadLen){
        recvLen = recv(fd, buff, payloadLen); // actual recv
        if(recvLen != payloadLen){
             // fatal error
        }
        // do something with received payload
     }
}
```

As you can see, i have first called recv with MSG_PEEK flag to ensure is there really 4 bytes available or not, then received actual header. same for payload

Comment: Even synchronous, you are not guaranteed to receive the number of bytes you requested.  Always check the result for the correct length.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 4; ) { int recvLen = recv(fd, buff, 1); if (recvLen == 1) { len << 1; len += buff; ++i; }}` is not exaggerated code for receiving multiple bytes and it will make make the program noticeably slower.  It is even still lacking code that handles socket errors (recvLen <= 0).

Comment: I was missed, usually i will call recv with MSG_PEEK to ensure is there N bytes available or not

Comment: No problem, that is another approach, however, it would be interesting to see your else-code

Comment: I just saw my typo in the second comment.  "it will make make the..." should obviously be "it will not make the..."

Comment: Given how common "length -> data" protocols are (e.g. DNS uses a 2 byte length header when carried in TCP) I wonder why no-one ever created a system call that allows such a packet to be read in a single go rather than having to perform two separate syscalls (with associated context switches)